# Error gradle, duplicate entry: org/ksoap2/serialization/MarshalFloat.class

Tags: java, android, gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1252'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ejemplo.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled = true
        versionCode 32
        versionName "2.91"
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases' }
        }
    }


}



dependencies {
    compile project(':formaxComponents')
    compile project(':formaxCore')
    compile project(':nMComponents')
    compile project(':librarySOS')
    compile project(':libraryNM')
    compile project(':library')
    compile files('libs/android-smart-image-view-1.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/GoogleConversionTrackingSdk-2.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.jar')
    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.0'
    compile files('libs/bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar')
    compile('com.github.81813780:AVLoadingIndicatorView:getSampleApk') {
        exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'library'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'

}
```

**Me aparece el siguiente error:**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':appEjemplo:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/ksoap2/serialization/MarshalFloat.class
```

Comment: Hola red2005, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en Español, seria de mucha ayuda para ti que coloques lo que estabas haciendo y parte del código que lanzó dicho error, así la comunidad podrá apoyar a resolver el problema. Te invito a leer el contenido del siguiente enlace: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Saludos

Comment: Solo actualice el android studio y el jdk. El error esta lineas arriba.

Comment: Cual version de jdk?

Comment: Aqui te dejo más información si te sirve: https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html?hl=es

Comment: es 1.8.0_91, revise el link y no me ayuda, sigue saliendo lo mismo